# Intent from notification is null

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am new with notifications, so please don't be strict...

I receive message from FCM, and make a notification:

```
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(ConstantsUtil.Firebase.TOPIC_UPDATE, ConstantsUtil.Firebase.TOPIC_UPDATE);
intent.setAction(ConstantsUtil.Firebase.TOPIC_UPDATE);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestID, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(messageBody)
        .setAutoCancel(false)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(requestID, notificationBuilder.build());
```

If application is running when device receives the notification - it works fine, open new activity and I can getExtras and getAction.

But, if app is closed and a notification is received, and then user clicks on it - than open new activity, but intent.getExtraString is null, the same with getAction.

how can I getAction and getExtras from notification Intent when app is closed?

Comment: How are you sending the notification?

Comment: does it metter ? with firebase message system

Comment: Yeah it does matter, the type of message sent (notification message or data message) can be determined by the method of sending. Eg: if you are sending from the Firebase console the message will always be a notification message which may require the message be handled in specific ways.

Comment: can u provide some example, please?

Comment: All messages sent from the Firebase console are notification messages. Notification messages may or may not contain a data payload, if it does not contain a data payload then calling getExtraString will be null.

Answer (score 0):

With Firebase you can't customize notification when app is closed. So you can't customize the intent of that notification. Maybe with the next release of Firebase they will add this function

Comment: i think it is doesn't matter from where notification was create. imagine that it was created in some other background service and u close app. than u tap on the notification which must open new app with extra

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are sending notification messages, either from the Firebase console or from the FCM REST API.

When notification messages are received when the app is in the background an automatically generated notification is displayed, not the one that you generate with your code. If that notification message did not contain a data payload then you would get null when trying to retrieve extras from it.

When the app is in the foreground you would receive the onMessageReceived callback and you can generate your own notification like you are doing in your question, there you are adding the extras to the intent of the notification. This would explain why when your app is in the foreground the notification has extras but when you are in the background the notification does not contain extras.

If you are sending the notification from the Firebase console be sure to add your required custom data in the Advanced options of the message composer. If you are sending from the API then be sure to include a data payload along with your notification message.

@Stan Malcolm,you are not the only person confused by this and we are updating the documentation to make this more clear.

Comment: thanks for your answer!
but my example core are inside onMessageReceived...
so now i confused even more...

Comment: onMessageReceived is not called for all messages.

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same issue. 
Notification message has two payloads, 1) notification and 2) data.
and I am sending the data that i need to put in extras in the data payload.

So According to the answer, it should work. But when i do getExtras(), it is giving me null. I also tried with getExtra() method, but the result is same.

Comment: The extras would only be available in the getExtras() if the intent is launched as a result of the user tapping the notification. Are you tapping the notification and still seeing no extras?

Answer (score 0):

You have two types of notification: 
 - Notification message, sometimes thought of a “display message”
 - Data message, which are handled by the client application

if you want to handle notification when the application is backgrounded you should send data message and use onMessageReceived method.
[image]